# Enable ApplicationInsights based on Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I want Azure ApplicationInsights to only be used in an ASP.NET Core application if specified by a Configuration value that is set in `appsettings.json`.

I put this in my `_Layout.cshml` to disable client-side insights:

```
    @if (Configuration.GetSection("UseInsights").Get<bool>())
    {
        @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
    }
```

But server-side telemetry is still sent, so I added this when its disabled via Configuration:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
```

This stopped Request and Exception data from being sent, but things like CPU usage were still being sent and visible on my Insights dashboard.

What I think would be the proper method is to enable the `.UseApplicationInsights()` extension on `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` conditionally, but this is a chicken and egg scenario since I don't have access to the Configuration settings until after the Host has been built. Is there somewhere I can fully disable insights after calling `BuildWebHost()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to completely get rid of any Azure Application Insights when disabled.

I created an Interface for the JavaScript snippet that gets injected for client-side telemetry:

```
public interface IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet
{
    string FullScript { get; }
}
```

With two implementations, one that wraps `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet` for when Insights are enabled:

```
public class InsightsJavaScriptSnippet : IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet
{
    private readonly JavaScriptSnippet _snippet;

    public InsightsJavaScriptSnippet(JavaScriptSnippet snippet)
    {
        _snippet = snippet;
    }

    public string FullScript => _snippet.FullScript;
}
```

And another that outputs an empty string for when they are not:

```
public class BlankJavaScriptSnippet : IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet
{
    public string FullScript => string.Empty;
}
```

I then register one or the other depending on the Configuration value. `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` will register `JavaScriptSnippet` which will then be injected into the constructor for my `InsightsJavaScriptSnippet`:

```
if (Configuration.GetSection("UseInsights").Get<bool>())
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);
            services.AddSingleton<IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet, InsightsJavaScriptSnippet>();
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet, BlankJavaScriptSnippet>();
        }
```

Then, I inject `IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet` into `_Layout.cshtml` instead of the Microsoft `JavaScriptSnippet`:

```
@inject MyApp.Services.IInsightsJavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
// ... snipped code
<head>
    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
</head>
```

Which adds nothing to the HTML if we aren't using Insights.

Answer (score 1):

> {   "ApplicationInsights": {
>       "InstrumentationKey": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"    }    }

You can control server side telemetry by the presence/absence of instrumentation key in appsettings.json.
You may have separate appsettings.json for each environment, and each can contain different instrumentation keys, or do not contain anything at all if you do not want telemetry to be sent to ApplicationInsights service as shown below.

> {   "ApplicationInsights": {
>       "InstrumentationKey": ""    }    }

Comment: That's what I've done now. I moved the configuration for it to `Startup` and set the InstrumentationKey to null if the option to Send Telemetry is false. I still get insights in the Output window but its `Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): `. Might be as close as one can get.